# Asp.net core controller function with return partial view with select2 not working and remote function validation is not firing in modal popup

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Select2 is not working and remote validation is not firing, this is only happens when I convert the code to modal popup but if not everything is working properly. What Am I missing in my code? Any advise or help much appreciated.. Thank you

Here is my code the modal:

```
$('#tbProducts tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {
            var data = productsTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
            //alert(data.id);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "Products")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { id: data.id },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#EditUnitModal .modal-content').html(result);
                    $('#EditUnitModal').modal()
                }
            });
        });
```

Here is the controller `edit` code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        //code here
        return PartialView("__Edit", product);
    }
```

And here is my partial view `__Edit` code:

```
    @model intPOS.Models.Master.ViewModel.ProductViewModel


//code here

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('#Unit').select2({
            theme: 'bootstrap4',
            dropdownParent: $('#EditUnitModal')
        })

        $('#Category').select2({
            theme: 'bootstrap4',
            dropdownParent: $('#EditUnitModal')
        })

    })

</script>
}
```

And View model code:

```
[Display(Name = "Product Code"), Required]
    [Remote("CheckProduct", "Products", AdditionalFields = "Id", ErrorMessage = "Product already exists.")]
    public string ProductCode
    {
        get
        {
            return _productcode;
        }
        set
        {
            _productcode = value.Trim();
        }
    }
```

[Sample screen for not firing validation and select2 is not working:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc37a.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sections` aren't allowed in partial views. You can still use `modals` and partial views via Ajax for edit forms but there is a small modification you need to do in order for this to work:

1. Include all the necessary scripts in your page (this is mandatory as sections aren't allowed in partial views).
2. In your javascript code add these lines in order to parse the new form via jquery validation unobtrusive and your `select` elements via Select2.

```js
$('#tbProducts tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {
            var data = productsTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
            //alert(data.id);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "Products")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { id: data.id },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#EditUnitModal .modal-content').html(result);
                    //Here we parse the new form via jquery validation unobtrusive.
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#EditUnitModal .modal-content form')[0]);
                    //Here we initialize select2 for the selected elements.
                    $(".yourSelect2ElementClass").select2({//options...});
                    //Now we launch the modal.
                    $('#EditUnitModal').modal()
                }
            });
        });
```

Don't forget to remove the `section` from your partial view and include your scripts in the containing view.